How can I avoid letterboxing in my Android app while still supporting different device orientations?
Details:
I have an Android app that currently restricts its orientation to portrait mode.
I want to support different device orientations, including landscape mode, without causing the app to be letterboxed.
I am aware that letterboxing can occur when an app restricts its orientation and is displayed on a device with a different aspect ratio.
Additional Information:
I am using the latest version of Android Studio and the Kotlin programming language.
I have tried removing the orientation restriction from my app's manifest, but this causes the app to be stretched and distorted on landscape devices.
I have also tried using the resizeableActivity attribute in my app's manifest, but this does not seem to have any effect.
Desired Outcome:
I want to be able to support different device orientations in my app without causing the app to be letterboxed or distorted.
Additional Notes:
I am open to any suggestions or solutions that can help me achieve my desired outcome.
I am also interested in learning more about the best practices for supporting different device orientations in Android apps.
